# Access dynamic query with fields that may have a random "_"

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an excel file linked regularly and a field may have a random underscore "_" in the field name and it may be any random position and multiple times.  I need a query to clean out the underscores and reflect a corrected field name.   Is this possible?  For example, TABLE Name EMPLOYEE.  Field SSN.   Linked table may be Payroll_ Date or Payroll _Date.  Need field name to read Payroll Date. Can't use csv import because field positions vary as well in the file.

I'm fairly unsophisticated so don't know where to begin.

Comment: Using `tabledefs`, in a loop iterate through all fields and create a SELECT statement using modified field names (removed underscores and spaces) as aliases to the original names. Then create the query using this statement as the SQL property of it and append it to the `querydefs`.